# Algorithm for text filtering in NLP

Tags: java, sql, nlp, yql, text-mining

I'm making a question/answering system where my program reads data from internet and replies. For that I've made a java program to fetch data from YQL(yahoo query language)

```
    String baseUrl = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";

    String query = "select ChosenAnswer from answers.search where query=\"what is benzene ring\";

    String fullUrlStr = baseUrl + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8") + "&format=json";
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(fullUrlStr);
```

These are few of the result I get:

```
     "ChosenAnswer": "A benzene ring is a hexagonal (6 sided) ring of 6 carbon atoms.  Each carbon has one single bond and one double bond and one hydrogen so that each carbon has 4 bonds total.  The double bonds can alternate with the single bonds so that the result is a pi electron cloud in a ring shape above and below the plane of the carbon ring.  Benzene rings are very common and stable.  Because they have double bonds, they are not saturated.  If you saturated benzene, you would get cyclohexane."
    }
     "ChosenAnswer": "The IUPAC name for Benzene Ring is Benzene. It forms the basis for other IUPAC-named benzene derivatives like 1,2-dimethylbenzene etc. \n\nBenzene as a substituent group is called the phenyl group. (e.g. phenylethylamine\n\nBenzene is the IUPAC name for an aromatic hydrocarbon with the formula C6H6. It is also called benzol, or cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene. \n  \n\nUses of Benzene - As an industrial solvent for fats and oils, rubber, resins etc. As a starting material for dyes, drugs, perfumes and explosives and polymers For dry-cleaning of woollen cl.."
    },
    {
     "ChosenAnswer": "Benzene rings aren't metallic bonds.  Metallic bonds have the special property of having a \"sea of electrons\" which basically means that the electrons don't really belong to any single atom and just kind of flow around the element.  That is pretty much what makes metals conduct electricity well.  Other materials that don't form metallic bonds can conduct electricity as well, but usually these consists of certain ions so they have positive or negative charges.  A benzene rings doesn't have any charge with it so it's definitely not going to conduct electricity in this way."
    },
    {
     "ChosenAnswer": "You can draw the benzene ring in any orientation you would like, point up or side up, although a point up is more common.  You can also draw the alternating single and double bonds any way you want.  Although you should keep in mind that there really aren't alternating single and double bonds.  Every C-C bond in benzene is exactly alike and the bonds have characteristics that are half-way between a single bond and a double bond.  That is why you will also see benzene with a circle in the middle.  Benzene exhibits delocalized pi bonding that accounts for the many interesting properties of C6H6.\n\n."
    },
    {
     "ChosenAnswer": "Benzene and phenyl seems look the same because they are both aromatic and all aromatic compounds are based on benzene C6H6.  Phenyl or phenyl functional group is a hydrocarbon derived from benzene by removing 1 H, making it a C6H5 then attaching it to something else."
    },
    {
     "ChosenAnswer": "since benzene is an aromatic compound it is highly stable which means it has to be activated.you can activate benzene by adding electron donor groups to his ring(electron donor groups: -OH,-CH3).the electron donor groups stabilize the ring(they help to maintain resonance of the ring by delocalizing electrons into it) while the reaction occurs.benzene undergoes the reactions called electrophilic  aromatic substitution so check that out it will be more clear to you then."
    },
    {
     "ChosenAnswer": "C6H6 is benzene.  It is a 6 membered carbon ring each carbon has one H bonded to it and ONE resonance structure is with double bonds alternating between single bonds.  Ary is a radical meaning it is used to describe the benzene ring portion of a molecule that has some other group attached where one of the H's was.  C6H12 if you are discusing a single ring structure is cyclohexane."
    },
    {
     "ChosenAnswer": "benzene ring is mostly a compound of carbon and hydrogen in a hexagon shape structure"
    },
```

Now most of the answers here are opinion based answers(as we all know yahoo answers, where anyone replies). But i have to figure a way to filter these answers. Either i can make my query more efficient by using some joins etc or I can use some algorithm (maybe cosine similarity) to filter the answers and get max top 3 efficient answers. Please suggest me some algorithm which i can implement in java to get a relevant answer.
E.g in the case above the **first** 'ChosenAnswer' is the most suitable one.
(i know this is an enormous topic, i just want to know some good algorithm i can use here)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what do you mean by efficient.

You have many options and much depends on the types of the queries. For example if efficient means more scientific, then the possibility is to try to match the query to Wikipedia concept and then use TFIDF to calculate the distance between the Yahoo answers and Wiki document. The one with the higher similarity have higher importance, etc.

link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model

You can implement more weighting schemes as well and then use a combination of them to get the final weighting of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get the list of ChonsenAnswers, but I think the problem here is what you compare the possible answers against, considering the query has only a couple of words and you will obtain similar results for most of the answers.

I would take the significant words from the query (meaning no stopwords), and take their synsets definitions from WordNet. This way you will have more words to construct the frequency tables for tf–idf, or to construct a vector space model, or to train a naive-Bayes. This would improve your results regardless of the algorithm you decide to use.